# jquery datatable editable Feature not working after calling fncleartable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have datatable, initial loading it has last 24 hours data. There is a search criteria, based on search criteria I need to refresh the datatable. Here the problem is there are several columns, are editable. when I redraw the table, the editable feature is missing. I unable to find where is the mistake.
I am Using:

jquery1.7.2.js

jquery.dataTables.min.js(1.7.2)

jquery.jeditable.js(1.7.3)

jquery.dataTables.editable.js(2.3.3)

Here is My code

```
var table=$('#table').dataTable();
```

Editable:

```
table.makeEditable({
                sUpdateURL: "update",
                    aoColumns : [
                                  null,
                                 null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                  {   },
                                null,
                                   {  }
                                 ]
                });
```

Update table data:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/search',
            dataType : 'json',
            async : true,
            type: 'GET',
          data : dataObj,
            success: function (data) {    
               table.fnClearTable();
                table.fnAddData(data);
                table.fnDraw();
                    }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

fnClearTable() function is depreciated, please use

```
table.clear();
```

instead of

```
table.fnClearTable
```

.

Notes: keep c of clear small not big as given above.